# Using GestureDetector to catch gestures of MaterialButton child

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I want to have a `MaterialButton` to detect `onTapDown`, `onTapUp` and `onTapCancel`.

Unfortunately `MaterialButtons` only detect `onPressed`. So I wrapped it with a `GestureDetector` but for `MaterialButtons`, `onPressed` is `@required` so I set it to `() {}`.
The problem is that, even if I set the `GestureDetector` behavior to be translucent, if I tap on the button, only the `onPressed` callback of the `Button` will be triggered and I lose the `onTapDown` and `onTapUp` callbacks of `GestureDetector`. I only get the `onTapDown` to trigger if I long press the button, and when I release it, `onTapCancel` is triggered. I can never get the `onTapUp` to be triggered this way.

I still want the `MaterialButton` for its haptic/sound/visual feedback capabilities.

I tried not to set the `onPressed` on the `MaterialButton` at all, and (oddly) it still worked but the button was disabled and didn't give any feedback at all.

```dart
GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTapDown: (_) {
            th.handleTap(i, 0);
          },
          onTapUp: (_) {
            th.handleTap(i, 1);
          },
          onTapCancel: () {
            th.handleTap(i, 2);
          },
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Icon(icon),
            ),
          )
        )
```

Edit:
Thank you, Hugo Passos, for some reason I assumed `MaterialButtons` would never pass gestures to their children. I'm getting near but I'm still not there:
the only way I found to match the size of the Gesture is to "sandwich" it between two `Containers`, which doesn't look like a very elegant solution to me. By the way, even in this case, I run into two problems:

1: If I (quite easily) tap on the border of the button I still have the `onPressed` of the `MaterialButton` triggered instead of the `GestureDetector`'s callbacks. I thought it had zero size and so it couldn't never tapped. This problem doesn't show if I set the `GestureDetector` behavior to `opaque` (still strange to me).

2: **Most important**: I still can't get the native `MaterialButton` feedback capabilities unless I accidentally trigger its `onPressed`.

```dart
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        width: buttonSize,
        height: buttonSize,
        child: RaisedButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: () {print("onTap");},
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            width: buttonSize,
            height: buttonSize,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (_) {
                th.handleTap(i, 0);
              },
              onTapUp: (_) {
                th.handleTap(i, 1);
              },
              onTapCancel: () {
                th.handleTap(i, 2);
              },
              child: Icon(icon)
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must do the opposite. Instead of wrapping `RaisedButton` in a `GestureDetector`, wrap a `GestureDetector` in a `RaisedButton`. You also have to remove the `RaisedButton` padding, so you can expand the `GestureDetector` acting area.

```dart
RaisedButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Container(
    height: 40,
    width: 80,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => print('onTapDown'),
      onTapUp: (_) => print('onTapUp'),
      onTapCancel: () => print('onTapCancel'),
      child: Icon(icon),
    ),
  ),
),
```

### Edit

```dart
Center(
  child: RaisedButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    onPressed: () => print('onPressed'),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => print('onTapDown'),
      onTapUp: (_) => print('onTapUp'),
      onTapCancel: () => print('onTapCancel'),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 40,
        width: 80,
        child: Icon(icon),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

You'll get a little border that calls `onPressed`, though. If this bothers you, wrap this code in another `Container`, just like you did in your code.

You can easily get the native `RaisedButton` feedback capabilities by calling the `onPressButton` method at `onTapUp`. It'll have the same behavior.

```dart
RaisedButton(
  ...
  onPressed: onPressButton,
  child: GestureDetector(
    ...
    onTapUp: (_) {
      onPressButton();
      print('onTapUp')
    },
    ...
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you Hugo, I still have issues anyway. I edited my question.

Comment: Assuming I defined onPressButton elswhere like this:
```onPressButton() {print("onPressButton");};
``` It still doesn't work: onPressButton is called, but I don't get the Button feedbacks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by button feedback. The only feedback a button can provide is `onPressed`, right? If `onPressButton` is called, how didn't you get the button feedback?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I meant the UI feedback, like sound, vibration and splash effect on the button. With the last solution everything works like it should from a callback point of view, but my buttons don't give any visual feedback, the are just grey, working squares.